# How to run function with parameters using $timeout in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function inside my AngularJS controller. It looks like this;

```
polling_interval=1000;
var poll = function() 
{
  //Execution code
  $timeout(poll, polling_interval); 
}; 
poll();
```

It uses the `$timeout` service in AngularJS to keep calling itself. This works until I wanted to add parameters to this poll function. My code looks like this for the parameters added;

```
polling_interval=1000;
var poll = function(param1, param2) 
{
  //Execution code
  $timeout(poll(param1, param2), polling_interval); 
}; 
poll(param1, param2);
```

The syntax was not acceptable and I am at a loss now. How do I execute the function with parameters using `$timeout` in AngularJS? If this cannot be done, are there work-arounds to this problem? I would like to have my poll function accept parameters.

Comment: From 1.4.0 you can use ```$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);``` 
. Documentation [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because the first parameter type of the `$timeout` is function, you need to do like this:

```
polling_interval=1000;
var poll = function(param1, param2) 
{
  //Execution code
  $timeout(function() {poll(param1, param2)}, polling_interval); 
}; 
poll(param1, param2);
```

Comment: this helped me. Note however that it also works in the following as long as you don't have any function parameters:   'myFunc = $timeout(someFunc(), someMilliseconds);' As soon as someFunc() has a parameter, it does not work anymore and one has to do what you have suggested: 'myFunc = $timeout(function () {someFunc(param)}, someMilliseconds);'

Comment: why did you choose an anonymous function over bind()?

Answer (score 48):

$timeout is Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout. Naturally, just like setTimeout it supports passing additional parameters to the timed-out fn.

From AngularJS API:

```
$timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
```

**[fn]** (function) being your function 
**[delay]** (number) the delay in ms 
**[invokeApply]** (boolean) defaults to true, on true, the fn is run inside $apply, if false, it skips model dirty checking. 
**[Pass]** additional parameters! This is what you want!

How your code should look like:

```
polling_interval = 1000;
var poll = function(param1, param2){
    //Execution code
    $timeout(poll, polling_interval, true, param1, param2); 
}; 
poll(param1, param2);
```

This is the proper way to pass parameters to a timed-out fn. I hope you find this useful.

EDIT: This feature was added on January 22, 2015 (v1.4.1), prior to that version, the correct approach would have been:

```
polling_interval = 1000;
var poll = function(param1, param2){
    //Execution code
    $timeout(poll.bind(null, param1, param2), polling_interval); 
}; 
poll(param1, param2);
```

Comment: Best solution ! I was wondering how to do it prior to 1.4.1 so +1 again.

Other solutions using anonymous functions could give unexpected behaviours because of closures.

Comment: Using the `.bind()` approach do you know why the first argument must be `null`? it had me stumped for a bit when I didn't do this and the parameters were getting messed up.

Comment: @Will the first argument for `.bind()` is the `this`, the "context", that the function will be bound to.That is in fact, the main usage of `.bind()`. When using the additional parameters, you not only bind the context, but bind as many params as you pass to `.bind()`, so when you call the resulting bound fn, you are calling it with the `this` you set with the first param, and the params you set with the remaining params. Chek [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).Or maybe someone else can clarify more accurately

Answer (score 8):

Using an anonymous function would probably be the easiest way.

```
polling_interval=1000;
var poll = function(param1, param2) 
{
  //Execution code
  $timeout(function () { poll(param1, param2) }, polling_interval); 
}; 
poll(param1, param2);
```

Comment: why did you choose an anonymous function over bind()?