# Why does $timeout require functions with parameters to be wrapped in anonymous functions?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble using $timeout, and stumbled upon this solution on this site:

[How to run function with parameters using $timeout in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876031/how-to-run-function-with-parameters-using-timeout-in-angularjs)

While that answered the "how", it didn't address the "why". When you want to defer the execution of a function that requires parameters, using $timeout, why must it be wrapped in an anonymous function, and why is this also not necessary for parameterless functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$timeout` takes a function in parameter, and will call this function with no parameters.

For instance `$timeout(foo)` will result in `foo()` being called like this with no parameter, even if `foo` is supposed to work on some parameters.

So what people usually do is wrap the call of `foo`into an anonymous function to be faster, but it can totally be a named function such as in this example:

```
function foo(name) { alert('hello ' + name) }
function fooBar()  { foo('bar') }

$timeout(fooBar)
// or, as this is totally equivalent
$timeout(function() { foo('bar') })
```

Now for your information Javascript allows you to bind parameters to a function with the keyword `bind`. So our examples above are also equivalent to this:

```
$timeout(foo.bind(null, 'bar'))
```

Indeed, `foo.bind(null, 'bar')` is also a new function equivalent to `fooBar`, it is `foo` where `this` is set to `null` (since it is not used anyway) and the parameter `name` is forced to `"bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when the callback function is finally called, it's called without any argument.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does $timeout require functions with parameters to be wrapped in
>   anonymous functions?

`$timeout` does not *require* functions to be wrapped in anonymous functions. It's just that `$timeout` is not a friend of your function, so to speak, and will not pass arguments to the function you give him. Therefore, it makes no sense to give him a function that works with arguments.